# Passing default values to disabled input fields, but it is preventing input into enabled fields in Redux-Forms

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

Been fighting with this since yesterday, but this is as close to working as I can get. Just trying to pre-populate input fields with data received from server. Seems pretty simple, but I'm missing something apparently.

While I can get the fields to populate, it pretty much locks all the fields in the form from editing--ones that aren't pre-populated and should be editable.

This a snippet of what I have so far that kinda "works". The username is one where the server could respond with a value and if does it uses `renderDisabledField`: it populates the field with the `value` and disables it so it can't be edited. Otherwise, it should be editable. The password fields on the other hand should always be editable.

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.props.initialize(this.props.acctVal);
}

renderField(field) {
    const { 
        placeholder,
        type,
        name,
        meta: {
            touched, 
            error 
        } 
    } = field;

    return (
        <div className='form-group'>
            <input 
                className='form-control' 
                type={type}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                {...field.input} 
            />
            <div className='text-danger'>
                {touched ? error : ""}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

renderDisabledField(field) {

    const { 
        type,
        name,
        placeholder,
    } = field;

    return (
        <div className='form-group'>
            <input 
                className='form-control' 
                type={type}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                disabled
                {...field.input} 
            />
        </div>
    );
}

render() {
    if (this.props.permitRender) {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>

                    {this.renderAlert()}

                    <h4>Set Username</h4>
                    <p>Please enter the username you would like associated with your account. It must be at least 5 characters in length.</p>

                    <Field
                        name='username'
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='Enter Username'
                        onBlur={this.validateUsername.bind(this)}
                        component={this.props.acctVal.username ? this.renderDisabledField : this.renderField}
                    />

                    <hr />

                    <h4>Set New Password</h4>
                    <p>Type your new password twice. </p>
                    <p>It must be a minimum of 8 characters in length and contain at least:</p>
                    <ol>
                        <li>One uppercase character</li>
                        <li>One special character</li>
                        <li>One number</li>
                    </ol>

                    <Field
                        name='password1'
                        type='password'
                        placeholder='Enter New Password'
                        component={this.renderField}
                    />

                    <Field
                        name='password2'
                        type='password'
                        placeholder='Confirm Password'
                        component={this.renderField}
                    />

                    <hr />

                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <br />
            </div>
        );            
    } else if (!this.props.permitRender) {
        return ( 
            <Loading />
        );
    } 
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        errorMessage: state.auth.error,
        permitRender: state.auth.permitRender,
        questions: state.auth.questions,
        acctVal: state.auth.acctVal
    };
}

SetupUser = reduxForm({
    form: 'setup_user',
    touchOnChange: true,
    validate
})(SetupUser);
SetupUser = connect(mapStateToProps, { checkUsername, setupUser, verifyKey })(SetupUser);
export default SetupUser;
```

EDIT:

Almost forgot the reducer:

```
import {
    ACCT_VALUES
} from '../actions/authentication';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ACCT_VALUES:
            return { ...state, 
                acctVal: {
                    username: action.payload.data.username,
                    company: action.payload.data.company_name[0].company_name,
                    firstname: action.payload.data.first_name,
                    lastname: action.payload.data.last_name,
                    email: action.payload.data.email,
                    phone: action.payload.data.phone
                },
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }

    return state;
}
```

I've tried the various rendering it at different points in the life cycle:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Also tried following these through but haven't been able to get the desired results:

https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/initializefromstate/

[Redux form defaultValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631435/redux-form-defaultvalue)

[How to properly set default values using redux-forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402222/how-to-properly-set-default-values-using-redux-forms)

EDIT: Going in circles and retrying stuff I have already tried.

This works in getting a value into the field, but breaks when you try passing `state` or `props` into the `initialValues`.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        errorMessage: state.auth.error,
        permitRender: state.auth.permitRender,
        questions: state.auth.questions,
        acctVal: state.auth.acctVal
    };
}

SetupUser = reduxForm({
    form: 'setup_user',
    touchOnChange: true,
    validate,
    initialValues: {username: 'test1'}
}, mapStateToProps)(SetupUser);
SetupUser = connect(mapStateToProps, { checkUsername, setupUser, verifyKey })(SetupUser);
export default SetupUser;
```

Get the `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined with this and about a dozen other variations:

```
initialValues: this.props.acctVal
initialValues: {this.props.acctVal}
initialValues: {username: this.props.acctVal.username}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things one assumes to be a minor detail that are imperative.

In this case, what I had labeled as `acctVal` *really should have been* called `initialValues` like the documentation says:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        errorMessage: state.auth.error,
        permitRender: state.auth.permitRender,
        questions: state.auth.questions,
        initialValues: state.auth.acctVal
    };
}

SetupUser = reduxForm({
    form: 'setup_user',
    touchOnChange: true,
    validate,
})(SetupUser);
SetupUser = connect(mapStateToProps, { checkUsername, setupUser, verifyKey })(SetupUser);
export default SetupUser;
```

Then just could get rid of the:

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.props.initialize(this.props.acctVal);
}
```

Comment: `redux-form` is a great lib, but can be a pain in the ass sometimes, been there lol

Comment: Btw, don't know if it's appliable, but a tip: In the `component` attr of `username` `Field`, you could still use `this.renderField`, pass down `disabled` as a boolean prop and conditionally apply classes and attributes on your custom input render.

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz Thanks for confirming. I will take another look at that because I did try that by passing a boolean and it didn't seem to work. I probably did something wrong.